# AWS Python Lambda SNS Slack Json Format

Tags: python

SNS triggers Lambda when an S3 file upload event occurs.
The lambda code is below.

```
import json
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url = "MY-SLACK-WEBHOOK-URL"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    msg = json.dumps({
        "channel": "#python-test",
        "username": "SNS TEST",
        "text": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'],
        "icon_emoji": ""
    })
    requests.post(url=url, data=msg, headers=headers)
```

After that, when I check in my Slack, the message appears again in JSON format as shown below. How can I format only the information I want?

[image]